# Error loading com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$LoadingException in gms vision

Tags: android, qr-code

I am trying to implement a QR detector using `com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode`. The camera starts fine but when I build the detector object.

```
BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
        .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE | Barcode.ISBN)
        .build();
```

I got this error in the Logcat with no crash in the app:

> E/Vision: Error loading optional module
> com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode:
> com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$LoadingException:  No
> acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.

And receiveDetections doesn't detect anything. Can anyone knows how to solve this error?

**Edit**

I am using these versions of play-services libraries

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.2'
```

Comment: It seems like it is an open [issue](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues/164).